# Htaccess , redirección a una página web

Tags: html, html5, apache, .htaccess, apache2

Tengo un proyecto con PHP muy simple que al terminar la acción redirige hacia una página dentro del mismo proyecto.

Es un index.php que al finalizar mediante JavaScript hace un location.href a 3 posibles valores.

La estructura de carpetas del proyecto es esta

```
- assets
- gracias
    - index.html
- thanks
    - index.html
- obrigado
    - index.html
```

Lo tengo asi porque es necesario que al hacer redirect la url final sea http://www.midomonio.com/gracias/index.html
o bien  http://www.midomonio.com/thanks/index.html

Mi pregunta es si podria tenir estas 3 carpetas en una solo y mediante .htaccess hacer la redirección?

He probado algo tipo esto

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gracias.*$ http://example.com/gracias/index.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de muchas horas jugando con .htaccess lo encontré...de esta forma se puede hacer

```
# Activar RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f


RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ index.php [NC,R]


RewriteRule ^gracias/$  /gracias/es/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^gracies/$  /gracias/ca/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^obrigado/$  /gracias/pt/index.html [L]
```